# Stream based parsing and writing of JSON

Tags: ruby, json, parsing, memory, io

I fetch about 20,000 datasets from a server in 1,000 batches. Each dataset is a **JSON object**. Persisted this makes around 350 MB of uncompressed plaintext.

I have a memory limit of **1GB**. Hence, I write each 1,000 JSON objects as an array into a **raw JSON** file in append mode.

The result is a file with 20 JSON arrays which needs to be aggregated. I need to touch them anyway, because I want to add metadata. Generally the [Ruby Yajl Parser](https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby) makes this possible like so:

```
raw_file = File.new(path_to_raw_file, 'r')
json_file = File.new(path_to_json_file, 'w')

datasets = []
parser = Yajl::Parser.new
parser.on_parse_complete = Proc.new { |o| datasets += o }

parser.parse(datasets)

hash = { date: Time.now, datasets: datasets }
Yajl::Encoder.encode(hash, json_file)
```

**Where is the problem with this solution?** The problem is that still the whole JSON is parsed into **memory**, which I must avoid.

Basically what I need is a solution which **parses the JSON from an IO object** and **encodes them to another IO object**, at the same time.

I assumed Yajl offers this, but I haven't found a way, nor did its API give any hints, so I guess not. Is there a JSON Parser library which supports this? Are there other solutions?

---

The only solution I can think of is to use the `IO.seek` capabilities. Write all the datasets arrays one after another `[...][...][...]` and after every array, I seek back to the start and overwrite `][` with `,`, effectively connecting the arrays manually.

Comment: Are you bounded to Ruby? If not, try Jackson for Java. It has great streaming support.

Comment: Why can't you retrieve a record at a time from the database, process it as necessary, convert it to JSON, then emit it with a trailing/delimiting comma? If you started with a file that only contained `[`, then appended all your JSON strings, then, on the final entry didn't append a comma, and instead used a closing `]`, you'd have a JSON array of hashes, and would only have to process one row's worth at a time. It'd be a tiny bit slower (maybe) but wouldn't impact your system. And DB I/O can be very fast if you use blocking/paging to retrieve a reasonable number of records at a time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why can't you retrieve a single record at a time from the database, process it as necessary, convert it to JSON, then emit it with a trailing/delimiting comma?

If you started with a file that only contained `[`, then appended all your JSON strings, then, on the final entry didn't append a comma, and instead used a closing `]`, you'd have a JSON array of hashes, and would only have to process one row's worth at a time.

It'd be a tiny bit slower (maybe) but wouldn't impact your system. And DB I/O can be very fast if you use blocking/paging to retrieve a reasonable number of records at a time.

For instance, here's a combination of some Sequel example code, and code to extract the rows as JSON and build a larger JSON structure:

```
require 'json'
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.sqlite # memory database

DB.create_table :items do
  primary_key :id
  String :name
  Float :price
end

items = DB[:items] # Create a dataset

# Populate the table
items.insert(:name => 'abc', :price => rand * 100)
items.insert(:name => 'def', :price => rand * 100)
items.insert(:name => 'ghi', :price => rand * 100)

add_comma = false

puts '['
items.order(:price).each do |item|
  puts ',' if add_comma
  add_comma ||= true
  print JSON[item]
end
puts "\n]"
```

Which outputs:

```
[
{"id":2,"name":"def","price":3.714714089426208},
{"id":3,"name":"ghi","price":27.0179624376119},
{"id":1,"name":"abc","price":52.51248221170203}
]
```

Notice the order is now by "price".

Validation is easy:

```
require 'json'
require 'pp'

pp JSON[<<EOT]
[
{"id":2,"name":"def","price":3.714714089426208},
{"id":3,"name":"ghi","price":27.0179624376119},
{"id":1,"name":"abc","price":52.51248221170203}
]
EOT
```

Which results in:

```
[{"id"=>2, "name"=>"def", "price"=>3.714714089426208},
 {"id"=>3, "name"=>"ghi", "price"=>27.0179624376119},
 {"id"=>1, "name"=>"abc", "price"=>52.51248221170203}]
```

This validates the JSON and demonstrates that the original data is recoverable. Each row retrieved from the database should be a minimal "bitesized" piece of the overall JSON structure you want to build.

Building upon that, here's how to read incoming JSON in the database, manipulate it, then emit it as a JSON file:

```
require 'json'
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.sqlite # memory database

DB.create_table :items do
  primary_key :id
  String :json
end

items = DB[:items] # Create a dataset

# Populate the table
items.insert(:json => JSON[:name => 'abc', :price => rand * 100])
items.insert(:json => JSON[:name => 'def', :price => rand * 100])
items.insert(:json => JSON[:name => 'ghi', :price => rand * 100])
items.insert(:json => JSON[:name => 'jkl', :price => rand * 100])
items.insert(:json => JSON[:name => 'mno', :price => rand * 100])
items.insert(:json => JSON[:name => 'pqr', :price => rand * 100])
items.insert(:json => JSON[:name => 'stu', :price => rand * 100])
items.insert(:json => JSON[:name => 'vwx', :price => rand * 100])
items.insert(:json => JSON[:name => 'yz_', :price => rand * 100])

add_comma = false

puts '['
items.each do |item|
  puts ',' if add_comma
  add_comma ||= true
  print JSON[
    JSON[
      item[:json]
    ].merge('foo' => 'bar', 'time' => Time.now.to_f)
  ]
end
puts "\n]"
```

Which generates:

```
[
{"name":"abc","price":3.268814929005337,"foo":"bar","time":1379688093.124606},
{"name":"def","price":13.871147312377719,"foo":"bar","time":1379688093.124664},
{"name":"ghi","price":52.720984131655676,"foo":"bar","time":1379688093.124702},
{"name":"jkl","price":53.21477190840114,"foo":"bar","time":1379688093.124732},
{"name":"mno","price":40.99364022416619,"foo":"bar","time":1379688093.124758},
{"name":"pqr","price":5.918738444452265,"foo":"bar","time":1379688093.124803},
{"name":"stu","price":45.09391752439902,"foo":"bar","time":1379688093.124831},
{"name":"vwx","price":63.08947792357426,"foo":"bar","time":1379688093.124862},
{"name":"yz_","price":94.04921035056373,"foo":"bar","time":1379688093.124894}
]
```

I added the timestamp so you can see that each row is processed individually, *AND* to give you an idea how fast the rows are being processed. Granted, this is a tiny, in-memory database, which has no network I/O to content with, but a normal network connection through a switch to a database on a reasonable DB host should be pretty fast too. Telling the ORM to read the DB in chunks can speed up the processing because the DBM will be able to return larger blocks to more efficiently fill the packets. You'll have to experiment to determine what size chunks you need because it will vary based on your network, your hosts, and the size of your records.

Your original design isn't good when dealing with enterprise-sized databases, especially when your hardware resources are limited. Over the years we've learned how to parse BIG databases, which make 20,000 row tables appear miniscule. VM slices are common these days and we use them for crunching, so they're often the PCs of yesteryear: single CPU with small memory footprints and dinky drives. We can't beat them up or they'll be bottlenecks, so we have to break the data into the smallest atomic pieces we can.

Harping about DB design: Storing JSON in a database is a questionable practice. DBMs these days can spew JSON, YAML and XML representations of rows, but forcing the DBM to search inside stored JSON, YAML or XML strings is a major hit in processing speed, so avoid it at all costs unless you also have the equivalent lookup data indexed in separate fields so your searches are at the highest possible speed. If the data is available in separate fields, then doing good ol' database queries, tweaking in the DBM or your scripting language of choice, and emitting the massaged data becomes a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, very, very comprehensive answer. Looking at all the possibilities I have, I guess this is the only choice for now. Maybe there will be a library that abstracts away from this, but for now I believe this is the best solution.

Comment: It's not hard to write this sort of functionality, and, because it's pretty specialized, there's not a lot of need for a gem or library to do it for you. This is data-processing 101, gluing a little DB access code together with something to massage the records and them output them. You're just complicating it a bit with the JSON. Wanting to process multiple records is an assumption that it'd be faster; The actual processing occurs record by record, and benchmarking would probably show that processing single records is plenty fast. Benchmarks are our friends.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible via [JSON::Stream](https://github.com/dgraham/json-stream) or [Yajl::FFI](https://github.com/dgraham/yajl-ffi) gems. You will have to write your own callbacks though. Some hints on how to do that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208679/how-can-i-process-huge-json-files-as-streams-in-ruby-without-consuming-all-memo) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978518/parse-large-json-hash-with-ruby-yajl).

Facing a similar problem I have created the [json-streamer](https://github.com/csapagyi/json-streamer) gem that will spare you the need to create your own callbacks. It will yield you each object one by one removing it from the memory afterwards. You could then pass these to another IO object as intended.

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called oj that does exactly that. It can do parsing and generation. For example, for parsing you can use [Oj::Doc](http://www.ohler.com/oj/doc/Oj/Doc.html):

```rb
Oj::Doc.open('[3,[2,1]]') do |doc|
    result = {}
    doc.each_leaf() do |d|
        result[d.where?] = d.fetch()
    end
    result
end #=> ["/1" => 3, "/2/1" => 2, "/2/2" => 1]
```

You can even backtrack in the file using `doc.move(path)`. it seems very flexible.

For writing documents, you can use [Oj::StreamWriter](http://www.ohler.com/oj/doc/Oj/StreamWriter.html):

```rb
require 'oj'

doc = Oj::StreamWriter.new($stdout)

def write_item(doc, item)
  doc.push_object

  doc.push_key "type"
  doc.push_value "item"

  doc.push_key "value"
  doc.push_value item

  doc.pop
end

def write_array(doc, array)
  doc.push_object

  doc.push_key "type"
  doc.push_value "array"

  doc.push_key "value"
  doc.push_array
  array.each do |item|
    write_item(doc, item)
  end
  doc.pop

  doc.pop
end

write_array(doc, [{a: 1}, {a: 2}]) #=> {"type":"array","value":[{"type":"item","value":{":a":1}},{"type":"item","value":{":a":2}}]}
```