# How can I process huge JSON files as streams in Ruby, without consuming all memory?

Tags: ruby, json, parsing, memory, yajl

I'm having trouble processing a huge JSON file in Ruby. What I'm looking for is a way to process it entry-by-entry without keeping too much data in memory.

I thought that [yajl-ruby](https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby) gem would do the work but it consumes all my memory. I've also looked at [Yajl::FFI](https://github.com/dgraham/yajl-ffi) and JSON:Stream gems but there it is clearly stated:

> For larger documents we can use an IO object to stream it into the
>   parser. We still need room for the parsed object, but the document
>   itself is never fully read into memory.

Here's what I've done with Yajl:

```
file_stream = File.open(file, "r")
json = Yajl::Parser.parse(file_stream)
json.each do |entry|
    entry.do_something
end
file_stream.close
```

The memory usage keeps getting higher until the process is killed.

I don't see why Yajl keeps processed entries in the memory. Can I somehow free them, or did I just misunderstood the capabilities of Yajl parser?

If it cannot be done using Yajl: is there a way to do this in Ruby via any library?

Comment: What version of ruby?  I ask because it sounds like the GC isn't letting go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978518/parse-large-json-hash-with-ruby-yajl

Comment: @Anthony: ruby-2.2.1

Comment: @bumpy: I'm looking for a way to easily do this with a library, I don't want to invent the wheel myself as it was done in that example. However if nothing fits my problem then that would be a good way to start trying, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both @CodeGnome's and @A. Rager's answer helped me understand the solution.

I ended up creating the gem [json-streamer](https://github.com/thisismydesign/json-streamer) that offers a generic approach and spares the need to manually define callbacks for every scenario.

Answer (score 6):

### Problem

> json = Yajl::Parser.parse(file_stream)

When you invoke Yajl::Parser like this, the entire stream is loaded into memory to create your data structure. Don't do that.

### Solution

Yajl provides [Parser#parse_chunk](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/brianmario/yajl-ruby/Yajl/Parser#parse_chunk-instance_method), [Parser#on_parse_complete](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/brianmario/yajl-ruby/Yajl/Parser#on_parse_complete%3D-instance_method), and other related methods that enable you to trigger parsing events on a stream without requiring that the whole IO stream be parsed at once. The README [contains an example](https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby/blob/master/README.md#parsing) of how to use chunking instead.

The example given in the README is:

> Or lets say you didn't have access to the IO object that contained JSON data, but instead only had access to chunks of it at a time. No problem!
>
> (Assume we're in an EventMachine::Connection instance)
>
> ```
> def post_init
>   @parser = Yajl::Parser.new(:symbolize_keys => true)
> end
>
> def object_parsed(obj)
>   puts "Sometimes one pays most for the things one gets for nothing. - Albert Einstein"
>   puts obj.inspect
> end
>
> def connection_completed
>   # once a full JSON object has been parsed from the stream
>   # object_parsed will be called, and passed the constructed object
>   @parser.on_parse_complete = method(:object_parsed)
> end
>
> def receive_data(data)
>   # continue passing chunks
>   @parser << data
> end
> ```
>
> Or if you don't need to stream it, it'll just return the built object from the parse when it's done. NOTE: if there are going to be multiple JSON strings in the input, you must specify a block or callback as this is how yajl-ruby will hand you (the caller) each object as it's parsed off the input.
>
> ```
> obj = Yajl::Parser.parse(str_or_io)
> ```

One way or another, you have to parse only a subset of your JSON data at a time. Otherwise, you are simply instantiating a giant Hash in memory, which is exactly the behavior you describe.

Without knowing what your data looks like and how your JSON objects are composed, it isn't possible to give a more detailed explanation than that; as a result, your mileage may vary. However, this should at least get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I like this idea of using EventMachine, but not sure how to send the file to the EM. Whould you mind showing a complete example?

JSON interestingly is an array of objects, not sure if that would cause any problems:

[
  {
    "key":"value"
  },
  {
   "key":"value"
  }
  ...
]

Answer (score 4):

Your solutions seem to be [json-stream](https://github.com/dgraham/json-stream) and [yajl-ffi](https://github.com/dgraham/yajl-ffi). There's an example on both that're pretty similar (they're from the same guy):

```ruby
def post_init
  @parser = Yajl::FFI::Parser.new
  @parser.start_document { puts "start document" }
  @parser.end_document   { puts "end document" }
  @parser.start_object   { puts "start object" }
  @parser.end_object     { puts "end object" }
  @parser.start_array    { puts "start array" }
  @parser.end_array      { puts "end array" }
  @parser.key            {|k| puts "key: #{k}" }
  @parser.value          {|v| puts "value: #{v}" }
end

def receive_data(data)
  begin
    @parser << data
  rescue Yajl::FFI::ParserError => e
    close_connection
  end
end
```

There, he sets up the callbacks for possible data events that the stream parser can experience.

Given a json document that looks like:

```js
{
  1: {
    name: "fred",
    color: "red",
    dead: true,
  },
  2: {
    name: "tony",
    color: "six",
    dead: true,
  },
  ...
  n: {
    name: "erik",
    color: "black",
    dead: false,
  },
}
```

One could stream parse it with yajl-ffi something like this:

```ruby
def parse_dudes file_io, chunk_size
  parser = Yajl::FFI::Parser.new
  object_nesting_level = 0
  current_row = {}
  current_key = nil

  parser.start_object { object_nesting_level += 1 }
  parser.end_object do
    if object_nesting_level.eql? 2
      yield current_row #here, we yield the fully collected record to the passed block
      current_row = {}
    end
    object_nesting_level -= 1
  end

  parser.key do |k|
    if object_nesting_level.eql? 2
      current_key = k
    elsif object_nesting_level.eql? 1
      current_row["id"] = k
    end
  end

  parser.value { |v| current_row[current_key] = v }

  file_io.each(chunk_size) { |chunk| parser << chunk }
end

File.open('dudes.json') do |f|
  parse_dudes f, 1024 do |dude|
    pp dude
  end
end
```